# Bluetooth - No device

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

I've got a Packard Bell Easynote ML65 with a integrated Bluetooth device. Well, after I installed Ubuntu 12.04 it says: "No Bluetooth-device found".

`lspci` and `lsusb` don't show a device.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you check to see if there is a Hardware Switch?

Comment: Where did you see that message? Can you confirm that the message says ***"device"*** (not *"adapter"*)?